# Consequences of unbuffered file I/O

Tags: ruby, io, buffer, stdout, stderr

What are the consequences of writing large amounts of data to disk using unbuffered file I/O (at least for everything above the operating system level)?

**Details:**

I'm writing a Ruby script that will execute another piece of code, capturing its stdout and stderr and writing them to a file. Apparently (in Ruby, at least), stderr is unbuffered and stdout is buffered, which in my case results in out-of-order output as the stderr lines get printed before some stdout lines.

It seems the solution is to make this portion of the code use unbuffered IO (with `IO.sync = true`). However, the piece of code my script is running will also be writing large amounts of text to disk. So I'm wondering what the consequence is of not using the Ruby buffer (only the OS buffer and below), and if it is significant, how else I can get around the ordering problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unbuffered I/O is slower than buffered I/O when write operations have small counts and the situation is reversed for large count write operations. In a middle range around 1,000 to 10,000 bytes per operation it doesn't make much difference.

You will also see slightly better performance when operations are aligned

Answer (score 0):

What `IO.sync` does is toggle automatic flushing of the buffer, but doesn't change the fact that it is still buffered.

What you might want instead is to bypass the buffering system altogether and use [IO#syswrite](http://apidock.com/ruby/IO/syswrite) instead:

```
STDERR.syswrite("Look ma, no buffers")
```

As the documentation says, you should pick either buffered or unbuffered and stick with it, as mixing and matching can cause issues.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology then. I don't need to use `syswrite`, just `flush`ing the streams solves my problem (wrong ordering of redirected stdout/stderr). My question is: what are the consequences of writing large amounts of text to disk while `IO.sync` is `true`?

Comment: Remember the buffer is flushed automatically when it is full anyway, so if the amount you're writing would hit that limit frequently, the difference is minor. Typically the buffer is on the order of 1-2KB.